# What is the most secure way to access clients' VPNs?

Tags: vpn, vmware

I'm looking to provide our clients with a secure way we can connect to their VPN when performing software services.

The issue is security. We want to make them feel at ease that we are connecting to their systems in the most secure way possible. I was thinking of connecting to the VPN from a VM and try to lock down the VM so the host system doesn't affect the VM/VPN if the host gets a virus or is hacked.

Any suggestions on how to most securely connect to VPN or ways to convince clients that just using VPN in general is the most secure you are going to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Software Vendors with privileged network access are increasingly used by hackers to gain access to sensitive networks. A good example of how a of how a software vendor with VPN access can lead to a massive data-breach is [the 2013 Target hack](http://krebsonsecurity.com/2014/02/target-hackers-broke-in-via-hvac-company/).

The point of a VPN is to segregate access. A Virtual Machine can also be used to segregates access, however if the host machine is compromised, then all of the tenant VMs are also boned. Simply saying that you use a VM doesn't automatically give you a separation of trust - this is just security theater.

Consider the following measures to improve  security posture:

- Use a dedicated machine for accessing this senstive network.
- Have a trained professional conduct regular internal-network security assessments of the protected
  network and all adjacent networks.
- Ensure trusted machines are regularly updated, and have endpoint
  security measures in place.